# MongoDB deserialization in C# when custom id field

Tags: c#, mongodb, poco

I've got following structure in the database:

```
{
      "_id" : ObjectId(""),
      "title" : "something",
      "id" : 1,
      (...)
}
```

Basicly i want to retrive data from following collection to my Class:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Topic
{
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is this code doesn't work -> executes with error message: 
 *Cannot deserialize a 'Int32' from BsonType 'ObjectId'*,
but this one does:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Topic
{
    [BsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int IdTest { get; set; }
```

Seems like deserialization desperatly tries to match class property with name "Id" with the ObjectId in database which is not correct because i explicitly declare that i want to match it with BsonElement("id") and not ("_id").

I appreciate any ideas how to make it works as I need to.

Answer (score 3):

Your "_id" stored in your mongo document is of type BsonType.ObjectId so when deserializing, the Serializer try to find a property with the name "Id" and with type of ObjectId. In your case it found matched name but not the right type which is int (int32 type in your class): my suggestion is to change

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

to

```
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
```

Or

```
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

Or to make your class inheriting from class Entity if you use MongoRepository :

```
     [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
     public class Topic : Entity
     {
       [BsonElement("title")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class TopicMapper
{
    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int Identity { get; set; }
}
```

and this:

```
var list = await col.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        foreach(var doc in list)
        {
            if(doc.Name != null)
               topics.Add(new Topic{
                Id = doc.Identity,
                Name = doc.Name
               });
        }
```